adding day by day data in the table from s3 buckets to catalog tables of databricks
Daily ETL jobs from S3 buckets to Data bricks. Data loading was ok.
Main problem is that existing data of the delta table was deleted when we loaded the current data via code.
Check if Delta table exists
delta_table_exists = DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, delta_table_path)

if delta_table_exists:
    # Append the new data to the existing Delta table
    daily_data_df.write \
        .format("delta") \
        .mode("append") \
        .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
        .save(delta_table_path)
else:
    # Delta table does not exist, create a new one
    daily_data_df.write \
        .format("delta") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .saveAsTable(delta_table_path)

even though i used this functions , but existing data still deleted. I requesting the solution from all of you.

Always add the tag for the programming language to your question so that people familiar with that language see your question. Make sure your code is a [mcve]. What happens when you run the code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].
